# Xcode how to fix "ghost lines" in text editor when embedding emoji in strings?

Tags: xcode, xcode7, syntax-highlighting, text-editor, emoji

I'm working on a 13" MacBook air with Xcode 7 and am running into an issue with ghost lines being displayed when using emoji in string literals.

If I include emoji into a string and hit enter, it is likely that Xcode will get confused about true line height, creating ghost lines. Until I do an action that causes screen refresh, I don't know where my cursor is on screen, and typing code becomes virtually impossible. Each new line can create ghost text like below.

How do I make Xcode 7 play nice with Emoji in strings?

[image]

PS. This issue does not happen at the top of a source file, as Xcode does not recalculate line height/position there, it happens when there are hundreds of lines.

Comment: What do you mean by "ghost lines"? What's actually wrong in the image you posted?

Comment: The line spacing is larger if emojis are involved. I also recognized that but there isn't much we can do except for filing radars.

Comment: This is an real issue if I am using emojis or using emojis in comments to keep track of certain things.